# Electrical Cable Detector Goes Off On Several Walls

Tags: electrical

I have the Bosch GMS 120 sensor detector that I have used to successfully install several wall-mounted shelves and bits of furniture.

There seems to be a problem with live wire detection in my home, in that on some wall surfaces on my first floor, I get a continual detection, even as far as 10cms from the wall.

If I place the palm of my hand onto the wall surface, the detection ceases, but the second I remove my hand it begins again.

**I have become concerned that there may be an unsafe current running through the wall.  Is this likely to be the case?**

Some steps I have taken to verify what is happening:

- I have borrowed another different detector with the same result
- I have determined that it only occurs if both of the ring mains for the lower two floors are switched on in the fuse cabinet
- I have isolated the behaviour to one external and two internal walls in the house (all of which are connected)

In addition, since we moved in we have had very, very high electricity bills with high usage.  Not sure whether this is relevant to the situation or not.

Here are some pictures to illustrate the above:

Alarm trigger without hand on wall:
[image: Without hand on wall]

Alarm not triggered when hand is on wall:
[image: With hand on wall]

Comment: We need to know the age of the home, has it been renovated, and what type of wiring? Can you photo the breaker panel open showing us the inside. What type of heat do you have? Do you have any large appliances or motors in this area (includes basement/attic) Do you live near power lines? Also, have you isolated circuit breakers to see which ones impact this/these walls?

Comment: @noybman The house is 120 years old, it's been renovated 3 years ago, but I don't know the type of wiring. I can photograph the breaker panel. The heating is a combi gas boiler.  No motors of any kind in the house other than the over fan.  We do not live near any power lines - all power lines in our area are underground.  The circuit breaker is just a ring main per floor

Comment: I assume that's what you'd have to do to find some phantom power draw in your house. Hopefully that's not the situation. I'm just saying you're trying too hard, but I await SE to prove me wrong. IME electrical problems have a way of presenting themselves rather quickly.

Comment: Given the age of the home, there's a good chance you have knob and tube. This would certainly make sense for what you are detecting. However, I'd also expect numerous updates since then, but that doesn't mean there isn't knob and tube in use. So along the lines of @Mazura comment, as long as you are secruing power, you can certainly hang shelves just do so thoughtfully. You may want to call an electrician to quote an update to give you peace of mind. this really should have no bearing on your electric bill. I would look more to sump pump, fridge, etc.

Comment: I'll (and probably others) will await a picture of the panel to tell you it's knob and tube (please get the wires going into the box... and even photo any runs you see in teh basement/attic for example). There could be other reasons you'd detect hot on a wall that is not there, the tool is just a guide to be safe/careful. Similar to "call before you dig" you still have to explore to be certain and do so cautiously. This is why I suggested you isolate indivdual circuits to determine if it is REAL power or not, and to narrow it down.

Comment: A total renovation 3y ago should have required a complete upgrade of the electric (a copy of the plans might put your mind at ease). I'd definitely be looking at the other equipment in the house as to why the high bills.

Comment: Agree with @Mazura except that I'd leave nothing to chance when it comes to power and contractors (or homeowners) doing something by the book. Definitely look at the things IN the home that use power, to isolate, whats using power. Isolate breakers and narrow it down.